# Calculate total litres required to fill carpark using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to work out how many liters of concrete can fit into a park. Len park: 30.2m | wid of the park: 10m | liters per sq/m: 6.6. I have attempted this and am new to python and know how to calculate the total. (30.2 * 10 * 6.6 = total). But I'm struggling to print the result.

```py
length = 30.2

width = 10

squared = 6.6

length = int(input('Length of park (m):'))

width = int(input('Width of park (m):'))

squared = int(input('Litres per square metre:'))

sum = length * width * squared # calculate total metres to get answer

print("Litres Required =",sum)

# print total amount of liters required
```

Comment: 1. You set the input variables twice. Choose one. Maybe delete the second set of them? 2. Change the variable `sum`. It's a reserved word ie. it has a specific meaning in python, can't be used a variable name. Change it to something like `total` instead. 3. When writing a question, use ``` code ```  to format your code to make it easier for people to read and help

Comment: from line 4 to 6 you're re-assign variables to another value I don't know why you assign variables at first

Comment: I don't understand how you struggle with printing the result. Is `print("Litres Required =",sum)` not printing the result?

Comment: @timothyh `sum` can be used as a variable name.

Comment: @mkrieger Thanks, I stand corrected. It's not a reserved word, it's a built-in function that can be reassigned a value. Nevertheless, I wouldn't use it as a variable name because you lose the ability to use `sum()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"30.2" is a float since it has a decimal point, not an `int`.

`sum` is a builtin function in python, so avoid using it as a variable name.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@9DsIwDIT3PIUFAy1CiB@JAYk3YGJhjlq3jUiT1HGEePoQJe3U8U733dnux4M11xg1mp4HeECnreRKGRe42j2Laztwkj5QjfV9V9dCfFW7Dr@zucr6KUjCdlWtmNCDQ4KSgBGTUxi2LHUi5qv2UAb3sJRtoZG6CVoyQgln2icBPTJI479IQjhShqvNPPbCKah8y@aQqTS1hZyZW@RoQxLpCa0YyQMtSIzX0/EizidxO97@) (note, since this is a website, the output is different than you running it normally)

```py
length = float(input('Length of park (m):'))

width = float(input('Width of park (m):'))

squared = float(input('Litres per square metre:'))

total = length * width * squared # calculate total metres to get answer

print("Litres Required =",total)

# print total amount of liters required
```